# Do I need PostGIS to get Points in range?

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, postgresql, distance, select

I'm going to build a table of places where each contains geographical coordinates (latitude and longitude).

In my basic request to the database, I want to get all records in range X km to the location with specific lat and lng.

For example, get the restaurants in the range 50 km from point: { lat: 12.345, lng: 67.891 }.

Is it right idea to use PostGIS for this kind of query? Or can I use plain SELECT query without PostGIS features?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are along the right idea, IMO in using PostGIS.

The [ST_Distance](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Distance.html)

> ST_Distance — For geometry type Returns the 2-dimensional cartesian minimum distance (based on spatial ref) between two geometries in projected units. For geography type defaults to return spheroidal minimum distance between two geographies in **meters**.

Here are some examples based in the linked documentation:

> --Geometry example - units in planar degrees 4326 is WGS 84 long lat 
>   unit=degrees
>   SELECT ST_Distance(
>           ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-72.1235 42.3521)',4326),
>           ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-72.1260 42.45, -72.123 42.1546)', 4326)
>       );
>   st_distance : 0.00150567726382282
>
> -- Geometry example - units in meters (SRID: 26986 Massachusetts state plane meters) (most accurate for Massachusetts)
>   SELECT ST_Distance(
>               ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-72.1235 42.3521)',4326),26986),
>               ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-72.1260 42.45, -72.123 
>     42.1546)', 4326),26986)
>           );
>   st_distance : 123.797937878454

Comment: Better to store the Coordinates as Geometry(Point) in the database, then its possible to create and use spatial indexes which will speed up the query a lot.